# Questions relating to Zend checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, zend-form

I am writing a code in zend and I want to create muliple checkbox code to select data and after clicking the submit button to view the Information in the database, the code works fine but when it gets to the database the field does not display the choosen box instead it writes "array" in that field. here is my form code below..any suggestions higly appreciated

```
  $Organisation_type = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('Organisation_type', array(
        'multiOptions' => array(
                            '1' =>' Start-up',
                            '2' =>' Sole Proprietor',
                            '3' =>' Partnership',
                            '4' =>' Close Corporation',
                            '5' =>' Company Trust',
                            '6' =>' Compny Propriety Limited',
                            '7' =>' Co-operative',
                            '8' =>' Non Profit Organization',
        )
    ));
    $Organisation_type->setLabel('Organisation type'); 
    $Organisation_type->setValue(array('Start-up', 'Sole Proprietor', 'Partnership', 'Close Corporation', 'Company Trust', 'Compny Propriety Limited', 'Co-operative', 'Non Profit Organization'));
```

Been trying this for a while and every method I use I get the same problem,Can you please help me or provide a code i could use.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a multicheckbox, like the value of a multiselect, will be an array (notice how you are assigning an array with the setValue function). You can convert the value to a comma-delimited string like this:

```
$value = implode(',', $Organisation_type->getValue());
```

Alternatively, you can loop through the multiple values like so:

```
foreach ($Organisation_type->getValue() as $k => $v) {
    // do something here
}
```